# regex parsing issue ansible

Tags: regex, ansible, regex-greedy

I am trying to grab the password via regex . But having difficulty grabbing the entire password:

```
Password: Wi!CYtB!%w8z    (Please change it immediately!)
```

This is the regex I wrote to grab it and it works:

```
[^Password: ].+[^    (Please change it immediately!)]
```

The problem starts if the password has (a or t or s or u or i at the end) not able to grab the entire password only grabbing upto z

`Password: Wi!CYtB!%w8za    (Please change it immediately!)`

Not sure how to fix this issue

Comment: Well, are you sure your regex works? I doubt it since the `[^...]` constructs here are negated character classes matching any char but the one specified inside the class. Try just `Password:\s*(\S+)` and grab capturing group #1 value. What is your tool/language?

Comment: It works by accident. It should be `Password:\s*\S+\s*\(Please change it immediately!\)`

Comment: I suggest you add more relevant code of yours to the post itself to show what the regex code environment is. It will help help you better and quicker.

Comment: I was working on ansible playbook. Trying to grab the output as a variable via regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the language you're using supports Positive Lookbehind, Try this regex

```
(?<=Password: )[^\s]*
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/8xxwhz/1/

- `(?<=Password: )` Positive Lookbehind is used here `(?<=)` to match whatever comes after this string `Password:`.
- `[^\s]` to match anything that is not a space.

If your language doesn't support Positive Lookbehind, you could use groups. Example:

```
Password: ([^\s]*)
```

Make sure that you will use group (1) for the password.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/8xxwhz/2/

Comment: FYI, `[^\s]*` is literally equal to `\S*`, saving a few bytes.